# ISO 8583 AMEX Card Issue

Tags: iso8583

We have made an implementation to ISO8583. Every transaction works except if we make a keyed transaction for AMEX cards,

Document states :

The Track 2 Data and Primary Account Number (PAN) fields are instances of numeric data elements that follow a different format: In the case where the variable length data has an odd number of digits, set the right-most half byte to X '0'.

but adding a 0 to AMEX Card number we get a INVALID CARD NUMBER response,
If we send 15 digit card number no response at all is received.

Also at some other place in document it is mentioned :

Bitmap 2 — Primary Account Number Field Name Description
Variable up to 19 digits (if needed, last ½ byte padded-binary zero), preceded by 1-byte Length Indicator.

Comments
This field identifies the card member‘s account number. Unlike most numeric fields, the Primary Account Number is left-justified. In this case, the rightmost byte is padded with a ½ byte binary zero (e.g., a three-position field, X ‘03 12 30‘).

Is there any thing special that we need to do for odd digit card numbers?

Comment: Are you simply prepending a 0 to the PAN or your adding the necessary 0-bit to the bit representation of the PAN?

Comment: @kolossus  thaks for reply ..... I just solved the issue.

I have appended the "0" at the end of PAN, as well i needed to keep the length indicator value as of original PAN. Eg. if PAN has 15 digits, i appended 0 to its right making it 16 length but when setting its length indicator provided it as 15 only.